# Html not connecting to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slideshow

So I'm trying to make a slideshow using js, I have asked for help on that and it's working in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/BACJE/), but it won't work in my local environment, so I'm wondering if I have some wording or something wrong somewhere that someone could help me see.

HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>slider</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>

    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="slider()">

    <div class="slider">
        <img id="1" src="slide_image1.jpg" alt="TV Deals"/>
        <img id="2" src="slide_image2.jpg" alt="Furniture Deals"/>
        <img id="3" src="slide_image3.jpg" alt="Electronic Deals"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS3

```
.slider {
    width: 990px;
    height: 270px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-image: url('ajax-loader.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.slider img{
    border: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    slider();
});

function slider(){
    var count = 1;

    $('#1').show();

    (function slide(){
        $('.slider img').hide();

        if (count > 3) {count = 1;} // makes this a loop

        $('#'+count).fadeIn('slow');
        count += 1;

        setTimeout(function () {
            slide();
        }, 5000);
    })();
}
```

Is my "onload" command correct? I'm using Web Expression as a designer and I actually went in through the url path for each and ever image and selected the image, so I know the paths are correct (did the same thing for the js). The JavaScript itself is called "slider.js" could this affect my code in anyway? This is my first attempt at doing one of these so I have no idea what's causing it to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you say local environment, is it running on your computer under the `file://` protocol? (i.e., when you look at it is it something like `file://C:\My\Files\index.html`) or with a server running over the `http://` protocol?

If it is the former, you need to change the script srcs from `//` to `http://` explicitly. `//` means "use whatever protocol the page is using", so that would mean it tries `file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js`, which obviously doesn't exist.

That's the only thing that jumps out at me as being off and is a common mistake when working locally.

Comment: If so, changing those `//` in the two googleapis.com script src's to 'http://' should do the trick.

Comment: awesome it's showing up now, but now it's just not sliding. The images flash in, then flash and stay, then flash out and the next in again.

Comment: Looking at your code more closely, I think you are doubling up on it, so it's being double-timed out. The `$(document).ready` bit is basically the same as onload, and is actually the preferred method, so just kill your `onload="slider()"` call completely.

Comment: Okay cool, now it's not double flashing, but it still doesn't slide off to the left with the new one coming in from the right like it's supposed to.

Comment: The JSFiddle you posted also doesn't slide off. It shows the first, then fades away quickly and the other fades in. It sounds like the behavior you are describing is exactly what I see in the JSFiddle.

Comment: Yeah it's fading out, but I want the image to slide off to the left and the next image to slide in from the right and replace it. I only want the very first image to fade it, I'm trying to figure out how to make it like a slideshow. I'm looking though the "animate" commands now trying to figure it out I think I need to used something like .animate('left') and then some if/else statement so that it hides the first image after sliding away and shows the second image as it slides in.

Comment: Just to keep things clean, you should probably fire up another question for that, as the question here was about getting the script to run.

Comment: Yeah I found a youtube video explaining the principles behind it, so I'm going to work on it by myself till I'm absolutely stumped and then I'll ask for help if I need to.